# PDF file not able delete, need solustion

Tags: pdf

i can't delete this been trying to delete, force delete using cmd, rename, change location, anyone had any solution on this?

[image: can't dlete the pdf picture]

Comment: I think it’s not the right exchange for this question (superuser.com would probably be the right place). Which error messages do you get when you are trying to delete this file?

Comment: no error messages when i try to delete the pdf file, noted I will go superuser.com had a look.

Comment: Check if you see the file also when you open the windows explorer and open your "Desktop folder". If you don't see it you can just press F5 to refresh your Desktop (when no window is shown)

Comment: it is showing at the file explorer, the pdf it self can't be open, delete, rename change location.